# d3 js bidirectional horizontal bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to plot a horizontal bi-directional bar chart using d3. I have got a sample from the fiddle. I have updated it as I need. But I end up with some issues.

Please find the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/binuabraham/9c3rsrk6/1/

I need that ticks from 6 - 30 there in my graph all the time. But when I change the values the x-axis breaks:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickValues(d3.range(6, 31, 2));
```

Also the gap between ticks changing as per the value changes. Can anybody help me with it?

Comment: How do you change the values? And how it *breaks*?

Comment: Actually I will use dynamic vales for generating the graph. In the fiddle , you can see the x axis not reaching 30. Also when I change the value 26 to 10 or something the graph breaks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you first set the x domain as

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([6, 30])
```

from 6 to 30

then later you set domain like this depending on the data

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                return d.value;
            })).nice();
```

So the fix is do one of the above once.

And remove the tick values `.tickValues(d3.range(6, 31, 2));`
you cannot set the tick value 31 since your data has max till 26.

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bcwt0ue9/)

**EDIT**

If you always want the domain to be 6 to 30 then add:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([6, 30])
```

and remove this line below:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                return d.value;
            })).nice();
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/05p37hvy/)

Comment: Is there any way I can keep that tick values from 6 - 30 in the graph? Actually that was the biggest issue I faced.

Comment: i have added an *EDIT* section hopefully it covers your question.

Comment: Thanks @Cyril. Exactly what I need.